# Kepler's Second Law of Planetary Motion. Solving for Theta at a known time in orbit.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The second law has been described to me above. I have taken a class on calculus and differential equations and am familiar with how to find a derivative. Given the earth's orbit I would say that the perihelion is theta of 0. Given an interval of 2592000 seconds (seconds per month) how can I use Kepler's second law to solve for the value of (THETA).Thank you.

P.S. I am also interested in the values of r and r's corresponding height at time t as stated in the law's description.

Comment: My mistake. r is the perihelion distance which is known to be 147,098,074 km. Which is different from the semi-major axis I had it confused with. That is if Theta 0 is perihelion then r is known when Theta = 0. So then on would have to use the aphelion distance of 152.6 million km in order to see an area come out of this function.

Comment: None of this really gets to the bottom of how to find theta for a known time in orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of the ellipse is $\pi a b$, so given that you know the period you know $\frac {dA}{dt}= \frac {\pi a b}{\text{1 year}}$  Then $\frac {d\theta}{dt}=\frac 2{r^2}\frac {dA}{dt}=\frac {2 \pi a b}{r^2\text{1 year}}$  Now use the orbit equation to replace $r$ with a function of $\theta$ and you have an equation you can integrate, at least numerically.